# Connecting iText pdf and SQLite database in Android

Tags: java, android, itext

How do I display exactly one data (specified row and column value ) from SQLite database to a paragraph in iText pdf? I used iText pdf and extracted the table from database but I cannot extract a specific data from it and add it to paragraph.

I am making a CV maker app and I need to display the user data from database to pdf using Android.

Comment: *Please help me asap* how about helping yourself by trying to write some code - if you have done this and have trouble with that code then explain what that you is and accompany it with the sample code

Comment: The requirement sounds so simple that it is hard to understand what the actual problem is. We could of course write an application based on assumptions regarding the actual requirements, but that's something that is suited for a platform for paid freelancers. That would be completely inappropriate on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Pick whatever is the unique column on the database(maybe a username) and use it to query the database for specific rows that contain the username, since it's a profile table is safe to assume that the user's profile will prop up just once.
Then you can get out specific columns from the returned cursor.

```
SQLiteDatabase db =  this.getWriteableDatabase();
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + your_table_name + " WHERE " +  username_column + " = ?";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {thUsersUsername});

If (cursor.getCount == 1){
cursor.moveToFirst();

//get a specific column eg address
String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(enterColumNameHere));
Toast.makeText(this, address, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show;
cursor.close();
db.close();
}
```

That's basically what you need.

Comment: @halfer no it shouldn't